# Catching CTRL+BREAK in a Windows application

Tags: windows, console, signals, break, ctrl

Heres a simple question - is there anyway that a non-console (ie a CWinApp) application can receive and process <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>BREAK</kbd>, it would appear SetConsoleCtrlHandler doesnt do the job nor the installation of signal handlers?

I unfortunately am working with a legacy CDialog based app which is run under the control of Microsoft HPC and HPC uses <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>BREAK</kbd> to cancel the program (assuming i guess that nobody in their right mind would have a non-console app running in the background)

Cheers.

Comment: What is happening when HPC attempts to cancel the program?  Does the program fail to stop, or does it stop without calling your handler first?

Comment: Does GetConsoleWindow return NULL if called within your application, when it is run from HPC?

Comment: Yes it returns NULL so looks like i am sunk. When HPC cancels the program i am assuming it just invokes the default handler (and thus ExitProcess) as my handler is never called yet the process terminates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling [AttachConsole](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681952%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with `ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS` should do the trick.  This will attach your process to the HPC console so that it can receive the control-break signal.  You should probably do this before calling [SetConsoleCtrlHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686016%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

If that doesn't work, try [AllocConsole](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681944%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead.  If HPC doesn't have a console of its own, it might be assuming that the sub-process will have created a new console group (this happens automatically for console-mode applications) in which case it will be sending a control-break signal to the sub-process PID.  If so, it shouldn't matter whether the console group was created automatically or explicitly.

You may wish to start by making sure that HPC is indeed sending a control-break signal (presumably via [GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683155%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) by checking that [SetConsoleCtrlHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686016%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) works as expected for a console-mode application.  If it is calling [TerminateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686714%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead then there is nothing you can do about it.